# If $f$ is odd and strictly decreasing prove $f^{-1}(x)=f(x) \Leftrightarrow f(x)=x \Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(x)=x$.

Tags: real-analysis

Where $f^{-1}(x)$ denotes the inverse of $f$.

There is this proposition that if f is stricly increasing then  $f^{-1}(x)=f(x) \Leftrightarrow f(x)=x \Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(x)=x$.

For $(\Rightarrow)$

Let $a$ be the solution to  $f^{-1}(x)=f(x)$ then $f^{-1}(a)=f(a)\Leftrightarrow a=f(f(a))$

If $a<f(a) \Rightarrow f(a)<f(f(a))\Rightarrow f(a)<a$, contradiction

If $a>f(a) \Rightarrow f(a)>f(f(a))\Rightarrow f(a)>a$, contradiction

For $(\Leftarrow)$ if $a$ is a solution to $f(x)=x$ then $f(a)=a \Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(a)=a$

So, the same thing isn't generally the case for strictly decreasing functions but I'm not exactly sure why. It probably stems from the fact that by definition the axis of symmetry between a function and its inverse is the increasing function $g(x):=x$. What our teacher quickly said at the end of the class was as follows from the title: If $f$ is odd and strictly decreasing then $f^{-1}(x)=f(x) \Leftrightarrow f(x)=x \Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(x)=x$.

Is this even true? Did I mishear? And if so, can a similar proof be used to prove it? I can't think of a proof that uses the definition of an odd function and how that could even help here.

Not sure what tag to use here so I apologize if this is mislabeled, this was in the context of a 12th grade maths class from the EU and the book cover does say "analysis".

Comment: Can now confirm that that’s what he meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is odd and strictly *decreasing*, this is FALSE. What is critical to note is that there are such functions $f$ that satisfy $f(x)=f^{-1}(x) \not = x$ for at least one $x \not = 0$; take for example $f(x)=-x$; then the relation $f(x)=f^{-1}(x) \not = x$ holds for *all* $x \in \mathbb{R}$. For *any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there are however, no odd strictly increasing functions satisfying the relation $f(x)=f^{-1}(x) \not = x$, as you already noted in the OP.

[If $f$ is odd, the equation $f(0)=0$ holds. Furthermore, each positive $y$, the value of $f(y)$ must be *negative* [because $f$ is strictly decreasing and $f(0)=0$]. Likewise, for each negative $x$, the value of $f(x)$ must be positive.

So $f(0)=0$, and $f(x)=x \implies x = 0$, and applying $f^{-1}$ to both sides of the equation $f(0)=0$ gives the equation $f^{-1}f(0)=f^{-1}(0)$. So $f(0)=f^{-1}(0)=0$.]